# How to delete lines without alphabet characters using regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have a code to clean up my xml file from tags and unnecessary information. Everything works ok except the last preg_replace, it doesn't remove lines that not content any alphabet character. The output includes lines like:

```
  153
  834
  4598
  6
  0
```

The code is below

```
$xml = file_get_contents('3377035.xml');

$a =  strip_tags($xml,"");
$a = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $a);
$a = preg_replace("/^([^A-Za-z]+)/", "", $a);

file_put_contents("new.txt", $a);
```

Comment: To remove a line that does not contain a letter you need `'~^[^\p{L}\r\n]+\R*~m'`. Add `u` after `m` if you have Unicode texts.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thx, yep, multiline flag did the job, thx)

Comment: Instead of "cleaning unecessary informations", extract the informations you want using a XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: I should add multiline flag:

```
$a = preg_replace("/^([^A-Za-z]+)/m", "", $a);
```